# How do I remove a table view in titanium mobile?

Tags: android, ios, tableview, titanium-mobile

Let's say I have a written a `tableView` in xml file.

```
<Alloy>
<Window>
        <TableView></TableView>

</Window>
</Alloy>
```

Suppose that I have an empty array received from backend response I would like to delete the `tableView` and insert a some other view having different elements in it. How do I do it??? Is this possible???

I can get it without using the layout for window tag but I want it with using the property of vertical layout.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `TableView` in a normal `View` and call `$.viewID.removeAllChildren()` on that view. Then create a new `TableView` and add it to the view: `$.viewID.add(TI.UI.createTableView({}))`

Edit: In my experience updating the existing `TableView`-data my be better in look'n'feel because the TableView will disappear and just reappear which is sort of abrupt.